# Kubernetes cert manager ssl error verify ACME account

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I can`t create wilcard ssl with cert manager, I add my domain to cloudflare but cert manager can`t verify ACME account. How i resolve this problem?

i want wilcard ssl for my domain and use any deployments how could i do?

**I find error but how i resolve,  error is my k8s doesnt resolve dns  acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org**

error is k8s dns can't find 
My k8s is

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3-k3s.1", GitCommit:"8343999292c55c807be4406fcaa9f047e8751ffd", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-12T04:56+00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Error log:

```
I0716 13:06:11.712878       1 controller.go:153] cert-manager/controller/issuers "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/issuer-letsencrypt" 
I0716 13:06:11.713218       1 setup.go:162] cert-manager/controller/issuers "level"=0 "msg"="ACME server URL host and ACME private key registration host differ. Re-checking ACME account registration" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="issuer-letsencrypt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="issuer-letsencrypt" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0716 13:06:11.713245       1 logger.go:88] Calling GetAccount
E0716 13:06:16.714911       1 setup.go:172] cert-manager/controller/issuers "msg"="failed to verify ACME account" "error"="Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: i/o timeout" "related_resource_kind"="Secret" "related_resource_name"="issuer-letsencrypt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="issuer-letsencrypt" "resource_namespace"="default" 
I0716 13:06:16.715527       1 sync.go:76] cert-manager/controller/issuers "level"=0 "msg"="Error initializing issuer: Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: i/o timeout" "resource_kind"="Issuer" "resource_name"="issuer-letsencrypt" "resource_namespace"="default" 
E0716 13:06:16.715609       1 controller.go:155] cert-manager/controller/issuers "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: i/o timeout" "key"="default/issuer-letsencrypt"
```

my Issuer

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: issuer-letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: yusufkaan142@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: issuer-letsencrypt
    dns01:
      providers:
      - name: cf-dns
        cloudflare:
          email: mail@gmail.com
          apiKeySecretRef:
            name: cloudflare-api-key
            key: api-key.txt
```

Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-api-key
  namespace: cert-manager
type: Opaque
data:
  api-key.txt: base64encoded
```

My Certificate:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: wilcard-theykk-net
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: wilcard-theykk-net
  issuerRef:
    name: issuer-letsencrypt
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: '*.example.net'
  dnsNames:
  - '*.example.net'
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: cf-dns
      domains:
      - '*.example.net'
      - 'example.net'
```

Dns for k8s

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["1.1.1.1","8.8.8.8"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with debugging DNS resolution function within your K8s cluster:

Spin up some container with basic network tools on a board:

`kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl --restart=Never`

From within `busybox` container check `/etc/resolv.conf` file and ensure that you can resolve Kubernetes DNS [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) `kube-dns`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local c.org-int.internal google.internal
options ndots:5
```

Make a lookup request to `kubernetes.default` which should get output with a DNS nameserver without any issues:

```
$ nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Due to the fact that you've defined `upstreamNameservers` in the corresponded `kube-dns` ConfigMap, check whether you can ping upstream nameservers: `1.1.1.1` and `8.8.8.8` that should be accessible from within a Pod.

Verify DNS pod logs for any suspicious events for each container(kubedns, dnsmasq, sidecar):

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name | head -1) -c kubedns

kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name | head -1) -c dnsmasq

kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name | head -1) -c sidecar
```

If you are fine with all precedent steps then DNS discovery is working properly, thus you can also inspect [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/dns-firewall/) DNS firewall configuration in order to exclude potential restrictions. More relevant information about troubleshooting DNS issue you can find in the official K8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

Comment: thanks i resolve problem with change coredns proxy settings /etc/resolv.conf  to normal dns (1.1.1.1)